# Debugging NextJS project with non-standard structure with WebStorm: "Debugger attached. > Couldn't find a pages directory"?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webstorm, next.js

The project I'm working on the `pages` directory is not in the project root, but some levels down, `/src/common/pages` and when I launch the debugger I get the error

> "Debugger attached. > Couldn't find a pages directory. Please create one under the project root".

I don't want to set the project root to the `common` directory...

Comment: doesn't look related to debugger. What is the result of running (not debugging) the same configuration?

Comment: error obviously comes from next.js. looks as if your app configuration has to be changed. see https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3570, https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2178, https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2202 and other tickets

Comment: Looks like NextJS issue, I don't think debugging serverside is working currently